# Assume Weak Axiom of Union, prove the Axiom of Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Weak Axiom of Union:

For any set $S$, there exists $U$ such that if $X \in A$ and $A \in S$, then $X \in U$.

Axiom of Union:

For any set $S$, there exists $U$ such that $X \in U$ iff $X \in A$ for some $A \in S$.

Proof: Assume that for any set $S$ there is a set $U$ such that if $X \in A$ and $A \in S$, then $X \in U$.

We need to show that there exists a set $W$ such that $X \in W$ iff there exists $A \in S$ such that $X \in A$.

Let $ W= \{X \in U:\text{there exists} \ A \in S \ \text{such that} \ X \in S \}$. ($W$ is a set by the Axiom of Comprehension)

Let $X \in W$ iff $x \in U$ and there exits $A \in S$ such that $X \in A$ iff there exists $A \in S$ such that $X \in A$.

Comment: I don't understand your proof of $\Leftarrow$, hopefully it is just a typo. Your proof of the other direction correctly mentions the relevant axiom (comprehension), but the first sentence of it makes no sense. Again, hopefully just another typo.

Comment: I'm not sure what "iff" statement the "$\Leftarrow$" and "$\Rightarrow$" parts of the proof are proving.  Also I don't think "Assume that for any set $S$, there exists $U$ such that $X\in A$" makes sense in context; $X$ and $A$ are not defined there.

Comment: This direction (<--) We are given. it's Weak axiom of Union.

Comment: It sounds like the "iff" statement you are proving is "$X \in U$ iff $X \in A$ for some $A \in S$".  However, this is not a statement but rather a logical formula involving the free variables $S$, $U$, $X$, and $A$.  When proving the Axiom of Union, you are given an arbitrary set $S$.  Then you need to introduce a set $U$, and only after that should you prove that "$X \in U$ iff $X \in A$ for some $A \in S$" holds for an arbitrary set $X$.

Comment: Note that you can't just fix $X$ and $U$ throughout the proof, because the set $U$ that is given by the weak Axiom of Union might not work for the Axiom of Union itself.

Comment: "This direction (<--) We are given. it's Weak axiom of Union." This makes no sense. Now I am not sure it was a typo. Instead, it seems confusion on your part. Even if an argument is trivial, one needs to be able to present it correctly.

Comment: Your use of comprehension is incorrect.

Comment: Your use of the weak axiom of union is also incorrect. The conclusion you draw is unjustified, even assuming that the two previous mistakes are fixed.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo. What about now? I made some correction.

Comment: No. $\{X\in S\colon X=X\}$ is just $S$. You do not need comprehension to prove that it exists. And certainly $S\notin S$, under the usual axioms of set theory.

Comment: The next sentence makes no sense. You said: There is $U$ with $X\in U$. But, first of all, there is no $X$ anywhere. The letter $X$ was a bound variable in the previous sentence. There is no actual set called $X$ in anything you wrote prior to this point. Second, this is not a consequence of the weak axiom of union. It follows from the power set axiom or even from pairing. This is not how you need to use the axiom. Third, sadly, nothing in this argument allows you to conclude the axiom of union.

Comment: The first sentence, "Let S be a set" is OK.  Andres has pointed out problems with the next two sentences of the alleged proof.  Neither of the two sentences after that makes sense either. It's true that, for any X, there is some U with X$\in$U, but this does not follow from the weak axiom of union.  And the final "Therefore" jumps to a conclusion quite unsupported by what went before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof: Assume that for any set S there is a set U such that if X∈A and A∈S, then X∈U.

We need to show that there exists a set W such that X∈W iff there exists A∈S such that X∈A.

Let W={X∈U:there exists A∈S such that X∈S}. (W is a set by the Axiom of Comprehension)

Let X∈W iff x∈U and there exits A∈S such that X∈A iff there exists A∈S such that X∈A.

Comment: I understand the point of the last line is simply to say "Clearly, the set $W$ is the set described by applying the axiom of union to $S$." Unfortunately, it is kind of nonsense the way you wrote it instead.

Comment: We are trying to prove the axiom of union, we cannot apply axiom of union to prove it.

Comment: Yes Nadia, perhaps what I meant is not a triviality. Unfortunately you still do not understand. But your argument is essentially correct.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote doesn't make sense to me, although as Andres says, you have identified the relevant axiom to use. Here is my hint.

Let $S$ be a set.  Use the weak Axiom of Union to get a set $U$ having a certain property with respect to $S$ (namely $\bigcup S \subset U$, but one shouldn't write it this way yet because this notation presumes that unions exist.)  Use comprehension to get a subset $U' \subset U$ having an even better property with respect to $S$ (namely $\bigcup S = U'$, but again one shouldn't write it this way yet because this notation presumes that unions exist.)  This set $U'$ will witness the (non-weak) Axiom of Union for $S$.